# Firebase get Map Object data

Tags: swift, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve an address I have stored in a Map object within Firebase.

But I can't seem to retrieve any data, When I print out the result it doesn't display anything.

Here is my Firebase Structure

[image: Here is my Firebase Structure]

This is the request I'm making to Firebase

```
let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as? String ?? "Null"
        let docRef = firebaseDB.collection("user").document(key)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let docData = document.data()

                let city = docData!["city"] as! String
                let country = docData!["country"] as! String
                let county = docData!["county"] as! String
                let lineOne = docData!["lineOne"] as! String
                let lineTwo = docData!["lineTwo"] as! String
                let postCode = docData!["postCode"] as! String

                print(city,country,county,lineOne,lineTwo,postCode)
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")

            }
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague as we don't know if the var's are populated correctly or where the code gets to before it *doesn't display anything*. When posting, please provide details about what troubleshooting you've done. For example, set a breakpoint at `if let document = document, document.exists` and step through your code. Which line isn't behaving as expected? Is the var `key` populated with the node name shown in the screenshot? `fwI4...`? Does the code even get to that line?

Comment: @Jay I can confirm that the Key is populated already.

Comment: Great. Now do some further troubleshooting per my comment, let us know the results and we'll take a look.

Comment: @OliverFerris As Jay says, we have no way of knowing what exactly is failing with what you've shared so far. For example, is the line `if let document = document, document.exists {` being called? If so, is `document.exists` true or false? If it's false, most likely your `key` value is wrong, so in that case try hardcoding the value and see if you can reproduce it with that. Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so these are steps you'll have to do on your own and then tell us the results.

Comment: Okay so I get an "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error" on the "let city = ... " line

Comment: Ok. That gives us more info. I posted an answer based on that comment - see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is crashing

```
let city = docData!["city"] as! String
```

it indicates a node does not contain a child of 'city'. Perhaps it's missing entirely or is City instead of city.

Force unwrapping a var (e.g. as!) which could potentially be nil is essentially stating 'Hey var, you will never be nil' and can lead to app crashes and instability.

A better way to handle this and protect your code is to properly handle data in the cases where it may not be what is expected.

A better method is to use nil coalescing like this, which provides a default value if city is nil

```
let city = data!["city"] as? String ?? "no city selected"
```

or if you want to work with nil then change the way you're reading the child nodes to

```
let city = document.get("city")
```

Keeping in mind that while this code won't crash, city *could* be nil in this situation so you need to handle that accordingly in the code following that statement.

You can also use if let statements

```
var aPlace = PlaceStruct()

if let city = document.get("city") as? String {
    aPlace.city = city
} else {
    aPlace.city = "Hometown"
}
```

or guard statements to protect your data.

Whatever the situation, don't force unwrap potentially nil vars unless you know they will *never* be nil - handle those vars that can be nil gracefully.